# If $Q$ is a nuclear operator on a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_n)$, are we able to conclude that $(\left\|Qe_n\right\|_E)$ is summable?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let

- $H$ be an infinite-dimensional separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space
- $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$
- $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space
- $Q$ be a nuclear operator from $H$ to $E$

> Are we able to show that $\left(\left\|Qe_n\right\|_E\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is summable?

If $H=E$ and $Q$ is nonnegative and self-adjoint, there is a specific $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $Qe_n=\lambda_ne_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and the nuclear norm of $Q$ is equal to $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda_n$. Thus, at least in that case and for that specific orthonormal basis, the claim is true.

But I don't know how we could argue in general. Is the claim wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $(\lVert Qe_n\rVert_E)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ need not be summable. Let $H = \ell^2(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$, with $(e_n)$ the "standard basis". Let $E = \mathbb{R}$ and $\xi \in H$. Then $Q \colon x \mapsto \langle x,\xi\rangle$ is nuclear, but

$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert Qe_n\rvert < +\infty \iff \xi \in \ell^1(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R}).$$